# Configure provisioning script for multiple instance VM vSphere deployment

Tags: linux, terraform, vmware, vsphere

I can't quite work out how to add a provisioning "remote-exec" section to my module, where I would like it to copy configuration scripts from the project directory and execute them. But when I add this module I can't seem to have it target the VM instance and as it has multiple network cards, I would just like to target the primary card.

I have used this to deploy a Linux VM via Terraform on a on-premise vSphere instance.

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = var.vsphere_user
  password       = var.vsphere_password
  vsphere_server = var.vsphere_server
  # If you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}
```

This is the sample Linux deployment script outlining the network part, which allows configuring of multiple network card to a VM

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Linux" {
  count      = var.is_windows_image ? 0 : var.instances
  depends_on = [var.vm_depends_on]
  name       = "%{if var.vmnameliteral != ""}${var.vmnameliteral}%{else}${var.vmname}${count.index + 1}${var.vmnamesuffix}%{endif}"
........
  dynamic "network_interface" {
    for_each = keys(var.network) #data.vsphere_network.network[*].id #other option
    content {
      network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network[network_interface.key].id
      adapter_type = var.network_type != null ? var.network_type[network_interface.key] : data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
    }
  }
........
    //Copy the file to execute
    provisioner "file" {
      source      = var.provisioner_file_source // eg ./scripts/*
      destination = var.provisioner_file_destination // eg /tmp/filename
      connection {
          type     = "ssh" // for Linux its SSH 
          user     = var.provisioner_ssh_username
          password = var.provisioner_ssh_password
          host     = self.vsphere_virtual_machine.Linux.*.guest_ip_address
        }
      }  
    //Run the script
    provisioner "remote-exec" {
      inline = [
        "chmod +x ${var.provisioner_file_destination}",
        "${var.provisioner_file_destination} args",
      ]
    
      connection {
        type     = "ssh" // for Linux its SSH 
        user     = var.provisioner_ssh_username
        password = var.provisioner_ssh_password
        host     = self.vsphere_virtual_machine.Linux.*.guest_ip_address
      }
    }
 }
} // end of resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "Linux"
```

So I have tried self. reference but thus far `self.vsphere_virtual_machine.Linux.*.guest_ip_address` this just shows the entire array of guest IPs?

Anyone able to point me in the right direction or even a good guide on terraform modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I notice is that the `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource doesn't have a property `guest_ip_address`, it is `guest_ip_addresses`. This does indeed return a list, so you would need to figure out how to select the IP you want from the list. I'm not sure if the ordering is predictable in vSphere. If I recall, it isn't.

The simplest approach, without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, would probably be to use the [default_ip_address](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#default_ip_address) as this returns a single address and selects the ip for the "most likely" scenario.

It looks like you're also setting up the host to be multi-homed. This adds additional complexity. If `default_ip_address` doesn't give you what you want, you'll need to resort to using some more complex expression to find your IP. Perhaps you could use the [sort](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/sort.html) function so the ordering is more predictable. You may also be able to "find" the IP using a [for](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html) loop.

Regarding building modules, if the above code is in a module, the first thing I would recommend is avoiding the use of `count`. Reasoning for this is explained in the following texts. Hashicorp has a lot of good documentation directly on their site. Also, the folks over at gruntwork also have a [blog series](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-create-reusable-infrastructure-with-terraform-modules-25526d65f73d) that they developed into a book called [Terraform Up and Running](https://g.co/kgs/JAc1WY). I recommend checking this out.